# How Create an Hyperlink from a sub form to a specific record in a form in Microsoft Access 2007/2010

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

Hello I am working on a project for school and I have a sub-form which with **StudentID** as the **primary key** and I would like to make EACH **StudentID** an **hyperlink** that links to a form that will show the full details of that student.

How can I do this? Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether your list of students is in a listbox or on a bound form you can capture the dblclick event of the row.  On the double click event you could launch your next form and use the OpenArgs property to pass it the student ID.  Then on your second form's load event you could run an SQL using the OpenArgs (StudentID) to get your desired data.

Comment: +1 for double-click. Why not use the where argument of Openform? It has the advantage of opening a single record, more suitable in this case.

Comment: Ah, good point, I've never thought to use that option as I'm almost always working with unbound forms where the resulting form does not yet have a recordsource. Iam-Roger either method should get you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you guys for the Input! :) so how can I accomplish what 'Remou" said? Please and Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what your record set SQL is but it would be along these lines. On your dblclick event of your listbox or row, you would enter: (DoCmd.OpenForm Formname,acNormal,,"StudentID = " & listbox.value & "") if your studentID is numeric, if it has letters as well then you would slightly amend to: (DoCmd.OpenForm Formname,acNormal,,"StudentID = '" & listbox.value & "'") to include the ' '. Best of luck